# Once the environments are vectorized, how do I have to gather immediate experiences for the agent?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, python, pytorch, actor-critic-methods, environment

My main purpose right now is to train an agent using the A2C algorithm to solve the Atari Breakout game. So far I have succeeded to create that code with a single agent and environment. To break the correlation between samples (i.i.d), I need to have an agent interacting with several environments.

```
class GymEnvVec():

    def __init__(self, env_name, n_envs, seed=0):
        make_env = lambda: gym.make(env_name)
        self.envs = [make_env() for _ in range(n_envs)]
        [env.seed(seed + 10 * i) for i, env in enumerate(self.envs)]

    def reset(self):
        return [env.reset() for env in self.envs]

    def step(self, actions):
        return list(zip(*[env.step(a) for env, a in zip(self.envs, actions)]))
```

I can use the class `GymEnvVec` to vectorize my environment.

So I can set my environments with

```
envs = GymEnvVec(env_name="Breakout-v0", n_envs=50)
```

I can get my first observations with

```
observations = envs.reset()
```

Pick some actions with

```
actions = agent.choose_actions(observations)
```

The `choose_actions` method might look like

```
def choose_actions(self, states):
        assert isinstance(states, (list, tuple))

        actions = []
        for state in states:
            probabilities  = F.softmax(self.network(state)[0])
            action_probs = T.distributions.Categorical(probabilities)
            actions.append(action_probs.sample())

        return [action.item() for action in actions]
```

Finally, the environments will spit the next_states, rewards and if it is done with

```
next_states, rewards, dones, _ = env.step(actions)
```

It is at this point I am a bit confused. I think I need to gather immediate experiences, batch altogether and forward it to the agent. My problem is probably with the "gather immediate experiences".

I propose a solution, but I am far from being sure it is a good answer. At each iteration, I think I must take a random number with

```
nb = random.randint(0, len(n_envs)-1)
```

and put the experience in history with

```
history.append(Experience(state=states[nb], actions[nb], rewards[nb], dones[nb]))
```

Am I wrong? Can you tell me what I should do?

Comment: I think you'd need multiple histories, one for each env

Comment: @SantiagoBenoit I answered my own question. Can you tell me if it is a fine way to do it?

Comment: Looks like the right idea - btw I made an edit to your histories list because it was just repeating the same queue

Comment: I have seen what you meant. indeed, if I run `histories = [deque(maxlen=5)] * 4` and  `histories[0].append(1)`, the output is `[deque([1]), deque([1]), deque([1]), deque([1])]` which is very annoying. Thanks @SantiagoBenoit! Can you explain that behavior? As you can see, instead I wanted `[deque([1]), deque([]), deque([]), deque([])]`

Comment: In Python, multiplication operator on list doesn't create deep copies of objects. Basically what is happening is instead of creating new queues, it is creating references to the same queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ExperienceSource():
    def __init__(self, env, agent, reward_steps):
        self.env = env
        self.agent = agent
        self.reward_steps = reward_steps

    def __iter__(self):
        histories = [deque(maxlen=self.reward_steps) for i in range(len(self.env.envs))]
        states = self.env.reset()

        while True:

            for idx, env in enumerate(self.env.envs):
                action = self.agent.choose_action(states[idx])
                state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)

                current_rewards[idx] += reward
                histories[idx].append(Experience(state, action, reward, done))

                if len(histories[idx]) == self.reward_steps:
                    yield tuple(histories[idx])

                if done: 
                    yield tuple(histories[idx])
                    state = env.reset()
```

Be aware that `self.reward_steps` is simply the value defined by `N-1` in the following formula $$Q(s,a) = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \gamma^i r_i
 + \gamma^N V(s_N)$$ and `self.env` is simply an instance of `GymEnvVec` class from the question.